# Why 180 degree rotation of the screen is not counted as a config change?

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, android-camera

Why a quick rotation of the screen in 180 degrees is not counted as a configuration change and thus it's not triggering `Activity.onCreate()` !? So I can't reorient my camera view! If you rotate by 90 deg it triggers config change each time.
I'll omit source code because my manifest has NO `configChanges` neither has `orientation` attribute. The activity has nothing special too. It seems that this is an intended behavior but I don't find any official info.

**Device**: hardware Nexus 5X

**Platform**: Android 7.1.1

Manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name="xyz.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:backupAgent=".provider.MyBackupAgent"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:restoreAnyVersion="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
    tools:replace="android:icon" >

<activity android:name="xyz.MyActivity"
        android:label="asdf"
        android:theme="@style/Theme" />
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarIconColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="actionBarInsetStart">@dimen/keyline_2</item>
</style>
```

styles-v19.xml:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarIconColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="actionBarInsetStart">@dimen/keyline_2</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Because rotating 180 degrees keeps it in portrait (or landscape) so none is needed.

Comment: Well, but it makes the camera preview upside down!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` for your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`
As described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) default orientation is `sensor` which ignores reverse portrait orientation. `fullSensor` allows all 4 orientations

**UPDATE**: Answer above doesn't solve the problem. The core problem is that changing orientation by 180 degrees (i.e. from landscape to reverse landscape) doesn't trigger activity re-creating. It's expected behaviour. In common cases layout for landscape doesn't differ from layout for reverse landscape.
If you want to change some of your views after rotating by 180 you can use [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)

Sample:

```
final WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
                    return;
                }
                Display display = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
                int rotation = display.getRotation();
                if (rotation != mLastRotation) {
                    // do something with your views
                    mLastRotation = rotation;
                }
            }
        };

 if (orientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
     orientationEventListener.enable();
 }
```

If your minSdk is 17+ you can also use [DisplayListener#onDisplayChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.DisplayListener.html#onDisplayChanged(int)) callback

Comment: @WindRider Can you update your question with code of your activity and AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can reproduce it with any activity. I did it with other activities and other app. This appears to be a platform-expected behavior.

Comment: @WindRider Please, check your manifest. I have made sample app contains activity with `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"`. It works as expected (all 4 orientations) on Nexus 5x with android 7.1.1

Comment: All 4 orientations is not the case. The problem case is a quick rotation upside-down. I've just added some xmls to the question.

Comment: @WindRider I don't see `android:screenOrientation` attribute in your manifest. Did you really try it?

Comment: I did of course. I've put a breakpoint on `MyActivity.onCreate()` - no hit!

Comment: @WindRider  Sorry. I didn't understand your question properly. Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Please use this in `AndroidManifest` file:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```